# How many Java out there that I should install on my computer?

Tags: java

If I go to firefox add on I got `Java Development Toolkit 7.0.110`

Then I got

`Java (TM platform)` that is disabled due to security and I don't know how to install

Then I've heard about `Java JRE`.

I thought I am installing Java. Which Java anyway?

Comment: JRE is available both as a standalone product and included in the JDK package (in fact, the JDK has both a public and private JRE, but let's not confuse matters any further! :) As mentioned below, JDK is only required if you want to code in Java. Any browser plugins in FF, IE etc. *always* refer to the JRE. (BTW, if you're installing the JRE then get the one which matches your OS and browser - 32 or 64-bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Development Kit (not toolkit) or JDK is used if you want to *create* java applications applets etc.

The Java Runtime Environment or JRE is used if you only want to *run* java programs (applets) that have been created by other developers.  The JRE is included with the JDK, and is also available separately

The [Java download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html#javasejdk) allows you to download whichever version you want, including previous (Java 6) and next (early access) versions.

Comment: What is Java TM Platform then? It's disabled by Firefox anyway and I want to uinstall it.

Comment: The platform is not a thing.  It's the whole shebang.  The JDK, the JRE, the virtual machine that java runs in (which is invoked when you run a java program) - these are all a part of 'the Java platform'.  Just uninstall any java JRE or JDK you have and that will uninstall the platform.

Comment: For simplicities sake, think of Java as a program that runs programs. Go into your program add/remove control panel, look for Java and remove all the installed versions you might find. It will then go away for Firefox as well as IE and Windows. Congratulations, you've now made your computer safe from Oracle Java.